# PHP search and Replace query

Tags: php

i want to search the symbols    \"   and replace it by  "

How can i do that , i am using the following code that is not working

```
$filenew = str_replace("\\"" , """, $filenew);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are almost certainly looking for [`stripslashes`](http://php.net/stripslashes).

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
$filenew = str_replace('\"' , '"', $filenew);
```

### [Working Example](http://codepad.org/jnbexIyw)

Comment: It worked :) ! is their an application that generates codes like these? I would be using lots of complicated expression like these ...

Answer (score 0):

```
$filenew = strtr($filenew, array('\"' => '"'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax highlighting should have given you a clue, but anyway, try one of these:

```
$filenew = str_replace('\\"' , '"', $filenew);

$filenew = str_replace("\\\"" , "\"", $filenew);
```

(If you look closely at the highlighting the SO code highlighter applies, you'll see that the comma is red, meaning you only have 2 parameters. Your escaping is wrong.)